# Add Css on a Html Class Tag With Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, arrays, stylesheet

I have a submit button which has a color red css style by default. How can I apply a css styling on it on the fly and seeing the result without refreshing the page using jquery?

I have an oncheck query and I want to put the code that will change styling above the return true;

My button

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submitForm" class="btn btn-primary-alt" value="Submit" onsubmit="return validate_age();" />
```

The css styling I want to apply on my submit button

```
.btn-primary-alt:hover {
background-color: #3b8410;
border-bottom: 3px solid #2a620a;
border-color: #2a620a;
color: #fff;
}
```

My jquery

```
if($("#age_18").is(":checked"))
{ 
  // This is where I want the css styling will happen.
  return true;
}
else
{
  alert("You must be above 18 years of age.");
  return false;
}
```

So basically when my checkbox is checked I want to add a css styling on my submit button. thanks

Comment: If you `return true` in the very next line the page will go to the new page before the changed CSS is visible. Do you wish to prevent the page-reload *as well as style* the check-box; or do you want the changed CSS to be visible and *then reload the page* (or go to the next page, etc...)?

Comment: Do it on-change of the radio button. What you are trying (assuming a document.ready) will fire only during the page load OR when submitting the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution would be to create a new class (not :hover). So for example

```
.checked{
 background-color: #3b8410;
 border-bottom: 3px solid #2a620a;
 border-color: #2a620a;
 color: #fff;
}
```

Then use jQuery to add or remove the class.

```
$('#submitForm').addClass('checked');
```

and

```
$('#submitForm').removeClass('checked');
```

Comment: Wow. This is what I exactly need. I'm about to do the same thing later which is to remove the class if the user unchecked the box. Thank for all your help. I wish I could tick all your answers for it works but I only need to choose one :D

Answer (score 1):

You can declare your css like this

```
.btn-primary-alt-hover,.btn-primary-alt:hover {
   background-color: #3b8410;
   border-bottom: 3px solid #2a620a;
   border-color: #2a620a;
   color: #fff;
}
```

and then you can apply this on your button like this

```
$("#submitForm").addClass('btn-primary-alt-hover');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#age_18").change(function(){
  if($("#age_18").is(":checked")) {
    // Add Your Styling Here to Submit Button...
    return true;
  } else {
    alert("You must be above 18 years of age.");
    return false;
  }
})
```

Your Logic is Perfect only one thing.

You have to call it's Change Function to check if the checbox is checked or not..

Answer (score 0):

I would keep the styles away form the CSS as you have it in your separate CSS file anyway.

I'd extend your CSS from:
.btn-primary-alt:hover to .btn-primary-alt-active, .btn-primary-alt:hover so that you can apply a class through jQuery to apply the styles. Your JS would look like:

// This is where I want the css styling will happen.
$('.btn-primary-alt').addClass('btn-primary-alt-active');

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#submitForm").addClass("Add your class name");
```

in your style sheet 
    .the-above-class-name {
     background-color:[Some color];
   color:[Some color];
}

OR

```
$("#submitForm").css({"background-color":"some color", "color":"some color"});
```

You can look at W3Schools for reference if you want to learn more about it
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css_classes.asp